# IntelliJ IDEA: how to put maven dependency into correct location of builded artifact

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, artifacts

I have java project in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3, that I am building into jar file (Build -> build artifacts... -> build), everything works well until I wanted to use external library (org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4), well no big deal, it work in IDE. But the extracted jar need that dependency. 
How to do that?

I have tried do Project structure -> Project Settings -> Artifacts -> and add as library.
[image]

Look at jar artifact:
[image]

The wanted dependecy jar is located in root folder of jar artifact, but still get this error, when try to use that code.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
....
....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 37 more
```

**What have I missed?**

Comment: It looks like you're wanting a "fat jar", where the jar has classpath jars inside it. This generally requires extra processing; I use Spring Boot, and the Spring Boot Maven plugin does this. There are also some other non-Spring-specific repackagers.

Comment: Thanks @chrylis, I have hoped that intelliJ does it for me :(

Well at the end, I am in hurry, and I need only one method _countMatches_

Comment: `private int countMatches(@NotNull String source, @NotNull String pattern) {
        if (!source.isEmpty() && !pattern.isEmpty()) {
            int count = 0;

            for (int idx = 0; (idx = source.indexOf(pattern, idx)) != -1; idx += pattern.length()) {
                count++;
            }

            return count;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment above, I have used my custom implementation instead of using whole library.

But in another project I have just run into same issue, this time with *nanohttpd*, which of course is not easy to implement myself like in previous usage :D

**I have found that the order of creation of artifact/maven dependency matters**
Because I have first added dependency like before, but before creating config for artifact.

And voilà, dependency has been extracted and the final artifactory works well :)
[image]